# issue convert date variable from character to data.frame or data.frame to character

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm extracting excel file to have multiple values in character including dates. From excel I take date_1. date_2 i get it from postgresql using dbgetquery which is always data.frame.

```
date_1 = 2017-05-22
class(date_1)    # this is "character"
date_2 = "2017-05-20"
class(date_2)   # this is "data.frame"

days <- difftime(as.Date(date_1), as.Date(date_2), units = "days")
print(days)

calculate_age = julian(as.Date(date_1), as.Date(date_2))
print(calculate_age)
```

I'm getting below 2 error.

```
1. "Error in as.Date.default(date_2) : 
  do not know how to convert 'date_2' to class “Date”" 

2. Error in UseMethod("julian") : 
  no applicable method for 'julian' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Anyone please suggest. I tried many. but no help. Also I'm new to R and Postgresql.

Comment: Have you tried `as.Date(as.character(date_2))`?

Comment: Works fine here. Try to restart your r environment. `class(date_1) [1] "character"` and `class(date_2) [1] "character"`. `date_2` should be class data frame.

Comment: @wernor : i get this error when i tried:  Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: What do you get as the output of `as.character(date_2)`?

Comment: @wernor :  for print(as.character(date_2)) I get this "15910".

Comment: @wernor : print(format(as.Date(as.character(date_2), "%Y-%m-%d")))
output is :     [1] NA

Comment: Toying with the `origin` attribute of `as.Date` could do the trick, although you need a numeric input: `as.Date(15910,origin='1973-10-28')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a good foundation, but your `as.Date` has not specified what date format you are supplying. By specifying that the date strings are 'yyyy-mm-dd', `days` is calculated using the `difftime( )` function.

```
date_1 = "2017-05-22"
date_2 = "2017-05-20"

days <- difftime(as.Date(date_1,format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                 as.Date(date_2,format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                 units = "days")

print(days)
Time difference of 2 days
```

Comment: Yes your answer is right when both dates are "character" and we could convert into date format and get the right result of difftime or julian. I am using this into my project several times. But I have problem getting the date value using dbgetquery which is always data.frame(date_2) . changing data.frame to character could solve my problem. But not able to convert to character format!